How to set max scale on instances based on scale of other instances
Good morning/afternoon/evening/etc Blender Family
Forgive me if my question is not immediately clear.
In short, I am trying to use geometry nodes to create a system where the Z Scale of instances on a set of points is changed over time with noise, and then the maximum scale of those instances is "remembered" and applied to new instances which are spawned on a copy of the original points.
It might be helpful to think of the old digital graphic equalisers where they have a peak meter which shows the peaks for a second or 2 after the previous max level was reached.
See the opening seconds of this old tutorial using Animation Nodes by Chris P.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjYf-tD2SqM
I don't want the peak scale to be remembered for just a few seconds.
I want the peak scale to be remembered and maintained until such time as a new maximum is reached.

I can get the scale from the first set of instances and scale the second set accordingly, but I can't figure out how to get this working in simulation nodes.

Before you point out my ignorance - I do understand that the scaling I am applying in the simulation zone is being animated over time and is not the result I am looking for. I know that I need to use attributes somehow, but I can't figure it out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Everything before a Simulation Zone is locked at frame 1. For all other frames, it uses the output of the zone. That's one issue I'm seeing.
